# Не могу никак понять в чем проблема данного кода на ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер

Задание такое: Написать программу определения високосного года по году введеннному с клавиатуры. При составлении программы использовать ветвления в коде

```
section .data
    msg db 'Enter a year: ', 0
    msg_len equ $ - msg
    leap_msg db 'Leap year!', 0
    common_msg db 'Common year.', 0

section .bss
    year resw 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Output message asking for year
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, msg_len
    int 0x80

    ; Read user input into year variable
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, year
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80

    ; Convert ASCII to integer
    sub word [year], '0'

    ; Check if the year is leap or common
    mov eax, [year]
    mov ecx, 4
    mov edx, 0
    div ecx
    test edx, edx
    jnz .leap
    mov eax, [year]
    mov ecx, 100
    xor edx, edx
    div ecx
    test edx, edx
    jz .leap
    jmp .common

.leap:
    ; Output "Leap year!" message
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, leap_msg
    mov edx, 10
    int 0x80
    jmp .exit

.common:
    ; Output "Common year." message
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, common_msg
    mov edx, 12
    int 0x80

.exit:
    ; Exit program
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80`
```

По итогу получаю ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Укажите, какой конкретно ассемблер вы используете, у разных ассемблеров могут быть свои особенности оформления кода. И попробуйте `section '.data'` в кавычках для начала.

Comment: Версия 1.73.04, section .data  в кавычках, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: Версия чего? `FASM`, `TASM`, `MASM`, ...? Какой конкретно ассемблер? А, вижу на скриншоте некий `flat assembler`. В общем, такая инфа должна быть текстом в вопросе, чтобы не рассматривать скриншоты.

Comment: В общем, у вас секции явно от другого ассемблера, для `FASM` они по-другому пишутся. Там, где вы подсмотрели пример, нужно посмотреть и **для какого конкретно ассемблера** этот пример, **под какую платформу** и **как его правильно компилировать**. Я кратко погуглил, там миллион разных тонкостей.

Comment: Диалекты ассемблера не совместимы между собой. Есть большая вероятность, что код у вас для nasm, а скомпилировать вы пытаетесь с помощью fasm. Также учтите, что код у вас для linux.

Comment: `section '.data' data readable` попробуйте, но вообще там для всех секций надо синтаксис менять, и наверное не только для них